# AX201 bluetooth range problem

Tags: bluetooth, hardware, firmware

I am using a HP ENVY Laptop 17m-cg0xxx with the **AX201 chip**. As the title says my bluetooth's range is too weak. So weak that it only goes about 5 to 6 centimeters from the laptop.

I have tried everything from updating my kernel to the 6.5.0-17-generic to try different firmware directly from the [linux kernel archives](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/). And copied ibt* and iwl* firmware files into /lib/firmware and /lib/firmware/intel respectively.

So I am wondering if somebody has a sollution for this. Maybe a specific firmware version for this specific chip.

I have seen similar questions to mine but about the wifi. My wifi works fine.

**Results of `dmesg | grep Blue`:**

```
[    4.047792] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.048107] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.048112] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.048114] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.048118] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.076124] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.4 build 0 week 11 2017
[    4.077132] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[    4.077135] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    4.077136] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    4.077138] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    4.077139] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    4.077140] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    4.084536] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-32-4.sfi
[    4.084648] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x24800
[    4.084650] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 249-27.23
[    5.732399] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    5.733123] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1609942 usecs
[    5.733166] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    5.748285] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 14791 usecs
[    5.748363] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[    5.752419] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-19-32-4.ddc
[    5.754277] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    5.755234] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.4 build 249 week 27 2023
[    5.757233] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[    8.002017] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.002022] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.002027] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.003439] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[    8.127164] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[   20.430166] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.430176] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.430183] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

**Result of** `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-02-08 17:26:20 CST; 1h 2min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 648 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 13910)
     Memory: 2.4M
        CPU: 572ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─648 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 08 18:28:01 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.83 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Feb 08 18:28:01 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.83 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Feb 08 18:28:01 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.83 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Feb 08 18:28:01 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.292 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/LDAC/Source/2
Feb 08 18:28:01 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.292 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Feb 08 18:28:01 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.292 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Feb 08 18:28:01 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
Feb 08 18:28:10 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: src/profile.c:connect_io() Unable to connect Hands-Free Voice gateway: connect to 20:64:DE:78:74:E1: Device or resource busy (16)
Feb 08 18:28:10 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: src/profile.c:record_cb() Connecting Hands-Free Voice gateway failed: Input/output error
Feb 08 18:28:14 jose-HP-ENVY-Laptop-17m-cg0xxx bluetoothd[648]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_20_64_DE_78_74_E1/sep1/fd5: fd(43) ready
```

Answer (score 1):

About all you can do is change the bt_coex_active setting for the iwlwifi module, in terminal

```
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlbt.conf
```

Reboot

This might not even help if there is a lot of activity on 2.4GHz